# Php and Command Line alias error: PHP shell_exec("MyCommandLineAlias"); returns sh: MyCommandLineAlias: command not found

Tags: php, command, command-line-interface, alias

I have an alias called MyCommandLineAlias in my bashrc. Is there any way to `echo shell_exec("MyCommandLineAlias");` without getting the `sh: MyCommandLineAlias: command not found`

I found this answer - [How to let shell_exec act like if commands are running inside mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426931/how-to-let-shell-exec-act-like-if-commands-are-running-inside-mac-terminal)

And tried

```
echo shell_exec("zsh -c 'MyCommandLineAlias'");
```

To which I get the following error:

`zsh:1: command not found: MyCommandLineAlias`

Is there anyway around this? Of course I can use the alias when I run them straight from command line but I need PHP to run the alias'. Is it even possible?

Comment: As stated in the link you provided, aliases are loaded as part of your bash profile - which is not loaded from within the PHP context.

Comment: So there is no way to call this? Prior to running the command?